# How to use infinite scroll if data is coming from server?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do infinite scroll. I am getting data from server and want to show 25 elements at time. When user scrolls down should show next 25 records.And main thing is it should scroll inner scroll bar.

```
httpHelper.get(urlName, false, function (err, response) {
    if (err) return err;
    getRecords(response.data.data, $scope.category);
});

var getRecords = function (data, category) {
    $scope.stocks.result = [];
    data.forEach(function (elem) {
        if (elem.duration === category) {
            $scope.stocks.result.push(elem);
        }
    });
};
```

Html :

```
<div class="row"
   ng-repeat="record in stocks.result | orderBy:stocks.symbol track by $index">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        {{record.Date|date:"dd-MMM"}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        {{record.symbol}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you faced ?

Comment: now i want use infinite scroll but my records are already stored as you can see. And  way to use  infinite scroll , is <div infinite scroll= loadMore()> . how will i load records ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add infinite scroll directive to your html

```
<div ng-repeat="record in stocks.result |orderBy:stocks.symbol track by $index" class="row" infinite-scroll="loadMore()">
```

And your loadMore function can be like this.

```
var getRecords = function (data, category) {
        $scope.stocks.result = [];
        data.forEach(function (elem) {
            if (elem.duration === category) {
                $scope.stocks.result.push(elem);
            }
        });
    };

function loadMore(){
    httpHelper.get(urlName, false, function (err, response) {
       if (err) return err;

       getRecords(response.data.data, $scope.category);
    });
}
```

Comment: how to get first 25 records n then next 25

Comment: If you are getting all data with one request then first request all the data and split / add it in loadData function.